# Оформление прямой речи (3)

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Прорешиваю *цт* и не могу понять, где ошибка в варианте. Помогите разобраться.

В этом предложении ошибки нет:
*«Можете осмотреть вашу комнату, — любезно предложила хозяйка и тут же попросила: — Только обувь снимите».*

В этом уже есть:
*«Который теперь час? — забеспокоилась Варенька и напомнила: — Нам обязательно надо успеть к ужину».*

Comment: Два предложения построены одинаково.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что оба предложения написаны верно (не знаю, правда, что такое "цт").
Вот что есть в справочнике Розенталя:

> **6.** Если в словах автора, находящихся внутри прямой речи, имеются два глагола со значением высказывания, из которых один относится к первой части прямой речи, а другой — ко второй, то после слов автора ставятся двоеточие и тире, причем первое слово второй части пишется с прописной буквы:
> *«Я тебя не спрашиваю, — **строго сказал офицер и снова спросил:** — Старуха, отвечай?»* (М. Г.); *«Покорно благодарю, — **отозвался Мешков, смиренно снял картузик, но сразу опять надел и поклонился, добавив торопливо:** — Спасибо вам большое, товарищи»* (Фед.).

"Прицепиться" здесь, считаю, возможно только к глаголу ***з**абеспокоилась* (или ***З**абеспокоилась*).
В подавляющем большинстве случаев авторы пишут его со строчной буквы, относя к глаголам говорения:
*― А долго он будет сидеть? ― **з**абеспокоилась Эльга* (Виктория Токарева);
*― С вами все в порядке? ― **з**абеспокоилась девушка* (Ольга Новикова);
*― Чего, чего? ― **з**абеспокоилась Алена. ― Читай, что написано!* (Людмила Улицкая).

Вот что есть в словаре-справочнике Жеребило (думаю, это наш случай):

> глаголы говорения в составе прямой речи
> <...> **2)** глаголы со значением внутреннего состояния и чувств (*спохватиться, недоумевать, обидеться, усомниться* и др.)...

[Слова автора внутри прямой речи](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=158#pp158)
[Термины и понятия лингвистики...](https://syntax.academic.ru/101/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8)